# how to show a specific div on click and hiding others

Tags: angularjs

New to AngularJS. I am trying to make 4 buttons.when user will click on button, a specific div will be displayed hiding other 3 DIVs.
Here is the code,

```
  <div class="active">
      <button ng-click="a"><h5>Button a</h5></button>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button ng-click="b"><h5>Button b</h5></button>
  </div>
  <div><button ng-click="c"><h5>Button c</h5></button>
  </div>
  <div>
  <button ng-click="d"><h5>Button d</h5></button>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="browser-icons"></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th class="align-right">Product ID</th>
      <th class="align-right">SKU ID</th>
      <th class="align-right">Seller Panel</th>
      <th class="align-right">Payment Medium</th>
      <th class="align-right">Quantity</th>
      <th class="align-right">Price</th>
      <th class="align-right">Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of metricsTableData" ng-if="a">
      <td><img class="tableimg" src="{{ ( item.image | baAppPicture )}}" width="100" height="100"></td>
      <td ngClass="nowrap">{{ item.browser }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.visits }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.purchases }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.percent }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.pmedium }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.quantity }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.price }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.status }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of metricsTableData1" ng-if="b">
      <td><img class="tableimg" src="{{ ( item.image | baAppPicture )}}" width="100" height="100"></td>
      <td ngClass="nowrap">{{ item.browser }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.visits }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.purchases }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.percent }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.pmedium }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.quantity }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.price }}</td>
      <td class="align-right">{{ item.status }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe simplify your example? Too many things not relevant to your question...

Comment: you can remove the table from the question. where is the code you tried to hide  the DIV?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you will need to do is ensure those ng-clicks have parentheses to call methods on your controller/scope (e.g. ng-click="c()")

If you do have a method called c on your controller/scope you can set a value (for example you may have a property called index, which is set to the value of whichever div is currently active).

Each div would have ng-if="index == x", where x is the index of the div.

It's a rudimentary way of achieving what you need, but should be adequate. Briefly:

```
<button ng-click="d()"><h5>Button d</h5></button>

var d = function() { index = 4; }
$scope.d = d;

<div ng-if="index == 4">Shown when button d clicked</div>
```